# PyQt4 QTimer doesn't work

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtimer

I'm new to use PyQt4 QTimer. I just copy the code from somewhere but seems it doesn't work. Can someone help me with this?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *



def startCount(): 
    timer.start(1000)



def showNum():
    global count
    count = count + 1 
    return count

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
count = 0
timer.timeout.connect(showNum)
startCount()
```

I expect to see the count incremented by the time, but the console shows nothing as the output. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Forgot to correct the return in showNum function, but it is not the problem of not showing anything on the screen. It comes with the same result when using print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `QTimer` cannot work without a running event-loop. Try this instead:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

def startCount():
    timer.start(1000)

def showNum():
    global count
    count = count + 1
    print(count)
    if count > 10:
        app.quit()

app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
count = 0
timer.timeout.connect(showNum)
startCount()

app.exec_()
```